# Why does C# object initializer has this behaviour?

Tags: c#, syntax

Why does C# *object initializer* has this behavior?

```
public class ChuckNorris
{
    public string Impact { get; set; }
}

public class Burnination
{
    public string Impact { get; set; }

    public ChuckNorris GetChuck()
    {
        var chuckNorris = new ChuckNorris
        {
            Impact = Impact // <- Why does the right hand "Impact" property here automatically refers to "Burnination.Impact" and not "chuckNorris.Impact"
        };

        return chuckNorris;
    }
}
```

Like the comment in the code above says. Why is that the right hand *Impact* property is pointing to *Burnination.Impact* and not the Impact property of the *ChuckNorris* class. How is this assumption being made that I (the developer) am referring to the Impact property of the underlying class?

Comment: I suppose because this.Impact is implied where this is Burnination and you will not initialize a property by itself which is uninitialized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, the expression on the RHS of the `=` is resolved and evaluated as it would be in any other context. So you *could* have:

```
ChuckNorris chuck1 = new ChuckNorris { Impact = "foo" };
ChuckNorris chuck2 = new ChuckNorris { Impact = chuck1.Impact };
```

It's only the identifiers on the *left* hand side of the assignment which are implicitly to do with the object being created.

Answer (score 2):

The scope belongs to class Burnination, hence implicit reference to "this".

Answer (score 1):

The others already responded to you, but note that:

```
public class ChuckNorris
{
    public string Kick { get; set; }
    public string Punch { get; set; }
}

var cn = new ChuckNorris
{
    Kick = "Dead",
    Punch = Kick
};
```

**This doesn't compile**

in an assignment in an `object initializer` you can't reference the fields/properties/methods of the object you are creating.